# undefined method in bootstrap-tagsinput with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ jquery plugin within my angularjs app, by using the method described in the page.

I have included both files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/viktor/public/js/tagsinput.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/viktor/public/js/ng-tagsinput.js"></script> // I have renamed those files.
```

added the following in my app mudule load:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'bootstrap-tagsinput'])
```

and lastly added the directive that's defined in the example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" bootstrap-tagsinput>
```

but I get the following error:

Error: [$compile:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=bootstrapTagsinput
    at Error ()
    at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.min.js:6:449
    at k (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.min.js:48:254)
    at Object. (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.min.js:48:353)
    at g.$digest (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.min.js:99:14)
    at g.$apply (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.min.js:101:369)
    at g (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.min.js:67:241)
    at w (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.min.js:71:181)
    at XMLHttpRequest.H.onreadystatechange (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.min.js:72:222) angular.js:9159
TypeError: Cannot call method 'filter' of undefined
    at Object.fn (tagsinput.js:68:35)
    at g.$digest (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.min.js:99:141)
    at g.$apply (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.min.js:101:369)
    at g (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.min.js:67:241)
    at w (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.min.js:71:181)
    at XMLHttpRequest.H.onreadystatechange (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.min.js:72:222)

it appears that in this line

```
var added = scope.model.filter(function(i) {return prev.indexOf(i) === -1;}), there is no method filter.
```

Anybody had the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a code how to use it on the page.

```
<bootstrap-tagsinput
    ng-model="cities"
    typeahead-source="queryCities"
    tagclass="getTagClass"
    itemvalue="value"
    itemtext="text">
</bootstrap-tagsinput>

<script>
    angular.module('AngularExample', ['bootstrap-tagsinput'])
    .controller('CityTagsInputController',
      function CityTagsInputController($scope) {
          // Init with some cities
          $scope.cities = [
            { "value": 1, "text": "Amsterdam", "continent": "Europe" },
            { "value": 4, "text": "Washington", "continent": "America" },
            { "value": 7, "text": "Sydney", "continent": "Australia" },
            { "value": 10, "text": "Beijing", "continent": "Asia" },
            { "value": 13, "text": "Cairo", "continent": "Africa" }
          ];

          $scope.queryCities = function (query) {
              return $http.get('cities.json');
          };

          $scope.getTagClass = function (city) {
              switch (city.continent) {
                  case 'Europe': return 'badge badge-info';
                  case 'America': return 'label label-important';
                  case 'Australia': return 'badge badge-success';
                  case 'Africa': return 'label label-inverse';
                  case 'Asia': return 'badge badge-warning';
              }
          };
      }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: 4-th line below *AngularJS support*

Comment: you may want to take a look at: [http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngTagsInput](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngTagsInput)

Comment: @john - Can you please help me with how it worked out? I have also done all what u have mentioned but for me bootsrap-tagInput HTL tag itself is not recognized and nothing is shown on UI

Comment: how do we track onchange or onadded method here in angularjs? can you please help?